# Side Scroller KnockBack

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a sidescroller on Unity in C#. Here's a script that allows the player to inflict a setback when he hits an enemy.

This script works when there is only one enemy on the map. But when there is 2, then the script does not work anymore. When I tap the 2nd enemy, then it is the first one who will take the setback 1 time on 2.
The script is on the player attack script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour
{

    public PlayerMovement playerMovement;


    public Transform attackpointDroite;
    public Transform attackpointGauche;
    public float attackRange = 0.5f;
    public LayerMask enemyLayers;
    public GameObject NounoursDroite;
    public GameObject NounoursGauche;
    public bool nounoursDroite = false;
    public bool nounoursGauche = false;

    public GameObject AttackPointDroite;
    public GameObject AttackPointGauche;

    public bool AttackDroite = false;
    public bool AttackGauche = false;

    public float attackRate = 2f;
    float nextAttackTime = 0f;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    public Enemy enemy;
    public bool KBEKnockFromRight;

    public Transform playerTransform;

    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        

        

        if (Time.time >= nextAttackTime)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.JoystickButton2) && spriteRenderer.flipX == false)
            {
                AttackDroite = true;
                attackdroite();
                StartCoroutine(ActiveNounoursDroite());
                nextAttackTime = Time.time + 1f / attackRate;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.JoystickButton2) && spriteRenderer.flipX == true)
            {
                AttackGauche = true;
                attackgauche();
                StartCoroutine(ActiveNounoursGauche());
                nextAttackTime = Time.time + 1f / attackRate;
            }
        }
    }

    void attackdroite()
    {
        Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackpointDroite.position, attackRange, enemyLayers);

        foreach (Collider2D hitEnemy in hitEnemies)
        {
            if (hitEnemy.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            {
                enemy.KBECounter = enemy.KBETotalTime;
                if (hitEnemy.transform.position.x <= transform.position.x)
                {
                    enemy = hitEnemy.GetComponent<Enemy>();
                    enemy.KBEKnockFromRight = false;
                }

                Debug.Log("Tah La droite" + hitEnemy.name);
                hitEnemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(1);
            }
        }
    }

    void attackgauche()
    {
        Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackpointGauche.position, attackRange, enemyLayers);

        foreach (Collider2D hitEnemy in hitEnemies)
        {
            if (hitEnemy.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            {
                enemy.KBECounter = enemy.KBETotalTime;
                if (hitEnemy.transform.position.x <= transform.position.x)
                {
                    enemy = hitEnemy.GetComponent<Enemy>();
                    enemy.KBEKnockFromRight = true;
                }

                Debug.Log("Tah La gauche" + hitEnemy.name);
                hitEnemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        if (attackpointDroite == null)
            return;

        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(attackpointDroite.position, attackRange);
    }

    IEnumerator ActiveNounoursDroite()
    {
        NounoursDroite.SetActive(true);
        nounoursDroite = true;

        if (nounoursDroite == true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.20f);
            NounoursDroite.SetActive(false);
            nounoursDroite = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ActiveNounoursGauche()
    {
        NounoursGauche.SetActive(true);
        nounoursGauche = true;

        if (NounoursGauche == true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.20f);
            NounoursGauche.SetActive(false);
            nounoursGauche = false;
        }
    }
}
```

i want that when i hit an enemy, he takes the knockBack`